# Code crashes unless I put a printf statement in it

Tags: c, debugging

This is a snippet of code from an array library I'm using. This runs fine on windows, but when I compile with gcc on linux if crashes in this function. when trying to narrow down the problem, I added a printf statement to it, and the code stopped crashing.

```
void _arrayCreateSize( void ***array, int capacity )
{
    (*array) = malloc( (capacity * sizeof(int)) + sizeof(ArrayHeader) );
    ((ArrayHeader*)(*array))->size = 0;
    ((ArrayHeader*)(*array))->capacity = capacity;
    // printf("Test!\n");
    *(char**)array += sizeof(ArrayHeader);
}
```

As soon as that printf is taken out it starts crashing on me again. I'm completely baffled as to why it's happening.

Comment: `void ***array` Oh my.

Comment: It's a pointer to an array of struct pointers.

Comment: Do you get any warnings from the compiler when adding `-Wall -Wextra`?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: I really wish this code checked the return value from `malloc(3)` to make sure it didn't return an error.

Comment: @ mu: `Foo **array = NULL; arrayPush(&array, f);` arrayPush calls _arrayCreateSize if the array is NULL
@sarnold: I just want to know why its only crashing without the printf. I don't care about much else until I get that fixed.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about the last line. What is it supposed to do? Anyway sounds to me like you're accessing some unallocated memory.

Comment: @nico: The memory is fine as far as I can tell. When it does work printf prints a perfectly cromulent memory address. The only time it crashes is when printf is not called somewhere in the function.

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing in that function and not somewhere else?  Do you have a stack trace of the crash? Is `stdio.h` included?  Is `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)` on the linux system (is the Linux system a 64-bit system)?

Comment: @Michael: int and void* are both 4. I have print statements immediately before and after this function and I don't hit the print after this function when I crash.

Comment: @alex I don't understand how you can simultaneously say "I don't care about much else" (in reference to validating the memory returned by malloc) and "the memory is fine".  You do not know if the memory is fine if you don't check that malloc returns valid memory.

Comment: @William: There are plenty of things that can be improved here: making it clearer, checking the return value, etc. In this case, the crash was not because of malloc returning an invalid value. You're right that it should be checked, but it was not the cause of this error, so I don't care about that at the moment. This question was specifically about why the printf made any difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line in the function is not doing what was intended.  The code is obscure to the point of impenetrability.

It appears that the goal is to allocate an array of `int`, because of the `sizeof(int)` in the first memory allocation.  At the very least, if you are meant to be allocating an array of structure pointers, you need to use `sizeof(SomeType *)`, the size of some pointer type (`sizeof(void *)` would do).  As written, this will fail horribly in a 64-bit environment.

The array is allocated with a structure header (`ArrayHeader`) followed by the array proper.  The returned value is supposed to the start of the array proper; the ArrayHeader will presumably be found by subtraction from the pointer.  This is ugly as sin, and unmaintainable to boot.  It can be made to work, but it requires extreme care, and (as Brian Kernighan said) "if you're as clever as possible when you write the code, how are you ever going to debug it?".

Unfortunately, the last line is wrong:

```
void _arrayCreateSize( void ***array, int capacity )
{
    (*array) = malloc( (capacity * sizeof(int)) + sizeof(ArrayHeader) );
    ((ArrayHeader*)(*array))->size = 0;
    ((ArrayHeader*)(*array))->capacity = capacity;
    // printf("Test!\n");
    *(char**)array += sizeof(ArrayHeader);
}
```

It adds `sizeof(ArrayHeader) * sizeof(char *)` to the address, instead of the intended `sizeof(ArrayHeader) * sizeof(char)`.  The last line should read, therefore:

```
*(char *)array += sizeof(ArrayHeader);
```

or, as noted in the comments and an alternative answer:

```
*(ArrayHeader *)array += 1;
*(ArrayHeader *)array++;
```

I note in passing that the function name should not really start with an underscore.  External names starting with an underscore are reserved to the implementation (of the C compiler and library).

---

The question asks "why does the `printf()` statement 'fix' things".   The answer is because it moves the problem around.  You've got a Heisenbug because there is abuse of the allocated memory, and the presence of the `printf()` manages to alter the behaviour of the code slightly.

#### Recommendation

1. Run the program under `valgrind`.  If you don't have it, get it.
2. Revise the code so that the function checks the return value from `malloc()`, and so it returns a pointer to a structure for the allocated array.
3. Use the clearer code outlined in [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr)'s answer.

Comment: I thought two underscores were reserved for compilers etc., while single underscores were for libraries (which this is). This particular function is not part of the public interface, it's just where the crash was happening. Making your suggested change solves the crash, but I'm still unclear as to why the printf has any effect at all. How does it alter the behavior of the code?

Comment: Or simply `*(ArrayHeader*)array += 1`.

Comment: @Alex: C Rationale §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers says: "Also reserved for the implementor are _all_ external identifiers beginning with an underscore, and all other identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter or an underscore" (emphasis in original). The standard itself says: "-- All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an upper-case letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. -- All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces". Be careful!

Comment: Now my question is why this worked at all; the original code with the `*(char**)array` is used on a bunch of windows code without any problem. Why does it work there at all? What does gcc do differently that makes it crash here but not there?

Comment: @Alex: not sure, but most likely it was an accident that it did not crash on Windows.  The chances are you were either overrunning the bounds of the array (but didn't notice), or you were reserving enough capacity that you did not overrun the bounds of the array.  But, given the weird behaviour with `printf()`, the chances are that something was scrambling your memory allocations, and writing out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary random crashing when adding seemingly unrelated `printf()` statements often is a sign of a corrupted heap. The compiler sometimes stores information about allocated memory directly on the heap itself. Overwriting that metadata leads to surprising runtime behavior.

A few suggestions:

- are you sure that you need `void ***`?
- try replacing your argument to `malloc()` with `10000`. Does it work now?

Moreover, if you just want arrays that store some metadata, your current code is a bad approach. A clean solution would probably use a structure like the following:

```
struct Array {
    size_t nmemb;    // size of an array element
    size_t size;     // current size of array
    size_t capacity; // maximum size of array
    void *data;      // the array itself
};
```

Now you can pass an object of type `Array` to functions that know about the `Array` type, and `Array->data` cast to the proper type to everything else. The memory layout might even be the same as in your current approach, but access to the metadata is significantly easier and especially more obvious.

Your main audience is the poor guy that has to maintain your code 5 years from now.

Comment: The nmemb field you suggest is not necessary here, as this is used only on structs pointer, so all things used on this will have the same size. Replacing the contents of malloc with 10000 crashes as well. When `malloc`ing, room for the array itself and the header is `malloc`ed, the `*(char**)array += sizeof(ArrayHeader)` *is* pointing at the first location behind the ArrayHeader, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Oops, that was my fault. You are right, the function's last line does what it's supposed to do. A slightly better way might be `*(ArrayHeader*)array += 1`. I removed the hint from my posting.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I get the error `error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘ArrayHeader’ and ‘int’)`

Answer (score 1):

Now that [Jonathan Leffler has pointed out what the bug was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672926/code-crashes-unless-i-put-a-printf-statement-in-it/5673885#5673885), might I suggest that the function be written in a manner that's a little less puzzling?:

```
void _arrayCreateSize( void ***array, int capacity )
{
    // aloocate a header followed by an appropriately sized array of pointers
    ArrayHeader* p = malloc( sizeof(ArrayHeader) + (capacity * sizeof(void*)));

    p->size = 0;
    p->capacity = capacity;

    *array = (void**)(p+1);   // return a pointer to just past the header 
                              //   (pointing at the array of pointers)
}
```

Mix in your own desired handling of `malloc()` failure.

I think this will probably help the next person who needs to look at it.

Comment: I had actually already made a very similar change but I for the sake of the question I posted the original code so that I could make sure I didn't mess anything else up. Thanks though.