# linked list segmentation fault fixed with cerr

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have the following code . what this code does is that it merges two sorted linked lists and then deletes both the linked lists and returns a new list :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node {
    public:
        node(int, node*);
        node* get_next() const;
        void set_next(node*);
        int get_item() const;
        void set_item(int);
    private:
        int item;
        node* next;
};

node* clone_and_destroy(node* a)
{
    node* new_list;
    node* prev;
    node* ret_val;
    while ( a )
    {
        new_list = new node(a->get_item(),NULL);
        if ( prev ){
            prev->set_next(new_list);
            prev = prev->get_next();
        }
        else{
        prev = new_list;
        ret_val = prev;
        }
        node* temp = a;
        a = a->get_next();
        delete temp;
    }
    return ret_val;
}

node* merge(node*& a, node*& b){
    if ( !a ){// cerr<<"\r";
        return clone_and_destroy(b);}
    if ( !b )
        return clone_and_destroy(a);

    node* smaller_node, *bigger_node;
    if ( a->get_item() < b->get_item() ){
        smaller_node = a;
        bigger_node = b;
    }
    else {
        smaller_node = b;
        bigger_node = a;
    }
    node* next_node = smaller_node->get_next(); 
    node* merged_list = new node(smaller_node->get_item(),smaller_node->get_next());
    delete smaller_node;
    merged_list->set_next(merge(next_node,bigger_node));
    a = NULL ;
    b = NULL ;
    return merged_list;
}

/*node* merge(node*& a, node*& b){
    if ( !a )
        return b;
    if ( !b )
        return a;
    if ( a->get_item() < b->get_item() ){
        node* a_next = a->get_next();
        node* merged_list = a;
        merged_list->set_next(merge(a_next,b));
        delete a;
        return merged_list;
    }
    else {
        node* b_next = b->get_next();
        node* merged_list = b;
        merged_list->set_next(merge(a,b_next));
        delete b;
        return merged_list;
    }
}*/     

void print(node* a)
{   
    while ( a )
    {
        cout << a->get_item() << " ";
        a = a->get_next();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

node::node(int _item, node* _next)
{
    item = _item;
    next = _next;
}
node* node::get_next() const
{
    return next;
}
void node::set_next(node* new_next)
{
    next = new_next;
}
int node::get_item() const { return item; }
void node::set_item(int _item)
{ 
    item = _item;
}

int main() {
    node* l1 = NULL, *l2 = NULL;
    cout << "Before Merging: " << endl;
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        l1 = new node(i, l1);
        l2 = new node(2*i-3, l2);
    }
    cout << "List 1 is: \t\t";
    print(l1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "List 2 is: \t\t";
    print(l2);
    cout << endl << "After Merging:" << endl;
    node* m = merge(l1, l2);
    cout << "List 1 is: \t\t";
    print(l1);
    cout << "Should be: \t\t[ ]" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "List 2 is: \t\t";
    print(l2);
    cout << "Should be: \t\t[ ]" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Merged List is: \t";
    print(m);
    cout << "Should be: \t\t[ -1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 7 ]" << endl;


    for (node* h = m; h != NULL; h = m) {
        m = m->get_next();
        delete h;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the important part of the code is the merge function , the rest are just tools for implementing this function . now a funny thing happens ! this code gets a segmentation fault when I run it , but when I was trying to debug my code I used cerr on the first line of the merge function ( it's commented ) and suddenly it worked fine !!! can someone please explain this to me !? what is this cerr doing ?! and how can I fix my code without this cerr and with minimum changes to the code !? now I know that cerr stops the couts from buffering but I dont think thats the case here !

Comment: Undefined behavior is strange. Use a debugger.

Comment: I have spent enough time on this ! even used a debugger , I need someone else's opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*prev is not initialized with anything and you are trying to access it. Hence seg. fault.

```
node* clone_and_destroy(node* a) { .. ..

     if ( prev ){
```

Edit:  Initializing it will null fixed the seg fault. but you check logic behind it.

```
node* prev = NULL;
```

Edit2: Why cerr fixes segmentation fault

[Code crashes unless I put a printf statement in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672926/code-crashes-unless-i-put-a-printf-statement-in-it)

Abstract from it "The question asks "why does the printf() statement 'fix' things". The answer is because it moves the problem around. You've got a Heisenbug because there is abuse of the allocated memory, and the presence of the printf() manages to alter the behaviour of the code slightly."

Comment: was just gonna write that, however if(prev) is not the access - the pointer may be a random pointer anywhere in memory

Comment: even if thats the case , why does the cerr fix it ?!?? and thanks , that actually fixed my bug

Comment: @Ashkan if(prev) only checks if a pointer is null, it could be invalid anywhere in memory (accessing a non-null pointer to invalid memory is a seg fault)

Comment: @AshkanKzme yes that not accessing it. But you can see line after that accessing it. Problem is that check fails as prev may have garbage value.

Comment: I got that ! now the question is why does cerr fixes it !?

Comment: @AshkanKzme prev->set_next(new_list); this line accessing garbage address and hence segment fault!

Comment: @AshkanKzme you can accept this answer if it fixed your error :)

Comment: @Digital_Reality why does cerr fixes the seg !? I will in about a few seconds

Comment: @AshkanKzme thats what I have explained two time in my comments.. :). Trying to access null ptr or garbage ptr will result in segmentation fault. Your if(prev) check was failing because it was not null (some garbage value). If you observe very next line is trying to access prev->... which is lead to segmentation fault. Now once you initialize with null then control wont come inside in if {}. I hope this explain!

Comment: what u said now three times still doesn't answer my question ! in the original question I said that when I put a cerr << "\r" ; in the first line , I don't get segmentation fault, and the things u said does not explain how cerr fixed the segmentation fault ! @Digital_Reality if u said that , please explain further !

Comment: @AshkanKzme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672926/code-crashes-unless-i-put-a-printf-statement-in-it

Abstract from it
"The question asks "why does the printf() statement 'fix' things". The answer is because it moves the problem around. You've got a Heisenbug because there is abuse of the allocated memory, and the presence of the printf() manages to alter the behaviour of the code slightly."

Comment: ok , so if you edit your answer and add this part too it would be helpfull